# Draw and generate an image by connecting pixel points in JAVA

Tags: java, image, image-processing, pixel, graph-drawing

I am very new to this are of java and I have no idea about how can solve fallowing scenario...

I have data set of 500 users. That contains

X and Y coordination with the system time for every 100 ms

I want to connect all pixel points according to system time and generate an image.

How can I do it with JAVA. Could anyone please give me some instructions to solve this problem?

Comment: [start here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and work your way up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :-) This question is too broad, and will probably be either downvoted, closed or both. For a start, see [Oracle Java 2D  tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html). When you get the basics, come back and ask about specific problems implementing your solution.